# how can i convert a string to a list to index using a for loop in lua?

Tags: string, lua, roblox

i'm trying to make a roblox game and i need a gui that shows text character by character but it just shows numbers this is my code

```
local frame = script.Parent.Parent
local currentText = ""
frame.Visible = false

local function showText (text, delayBetweenChanges)
    frame.Visible = true
    for letter in string.split(text,"") do
        local currentText = (currentText .. letter)
        script.Parent.Text = currentText
        wait(delayBetweenChanges)
    end
end
```

i thought it would add the next character to the already existing string and then display the final string

but it showed a number correlating to the position of that character in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
local label=script.Parent
local frame=label.Parent
frame.Visible=false
local function showText (text,delayBetweenChanges)
    frame.Visible=true
    label.Text=""
    for _,letter in ipairs(text:split"")do
        label.Text=label.Text..letter
        wait(delayBetweenChanges)
    end
    --frame.Visible=false
end
```

Comment: Or just `for letter in text:gmatch"."` if you want to iterate over characters.